# Android Studio Emulator Not Running. I Am Using Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have just installed Android Studio 2.3.3 but My Android Studio Emulator is not working after installed. 
It showing me this error:- 
an error report containing the information shown below, including system-specific information, will be sent to googles android team to help identify and fix the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwGQA.png)

Comment: Use the **Genymotion** because it is faster as compared to native android studio emulator and also consume less RAM space.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit AVD Settings -> Emulated Performance -> Graphics. Set Software - GLES 2.0. If not Working then try deleting and recreatiing AVD

Comment: Please make sure you specify Atleast 1gb of RAM and dont forget to use intel HAXM